# why does the order of fields return 0 rows, but move the field does

Tags: iseries, db2-midrange

I have two queries that return the same data, only the calculating field with the case is moved. I am using the Access Client Solutions "run query" to execute the query.

If I run this one

```
Select storenum,
       businessdate,
       kitchensenttime,
       parkcartime as delivertime,
       (parkcartime-kitchensenttime) as deliveryseconds,
       case
           when parkcartime-kitchensenttime>360 then 1
           else 0
       end as disastrouscount
from irislib.tblorder
where not(kitchensenttime='01/01/0001'
          or parkcartime='01/01/0001')
    and parkcartime>kitchensenttime
    and businessdate='05/18/2022'
```

No rows are returned.

While this one

```
Select storenum,
       businessdate,
       kitchensenttime,
       case
           when parkcartime-kitchensenttime>360 then 1
           else 0
       end as disastrouscount,
       parkcartime as delivertime,
       (parkcartime-kitchensenttime) as deliveryseconds
from irislib.tblorder
where not(kitchensenttime='01/01/0001'
          or parkcartime='01/01/0001')
    and parkcartime>kitchensenttime
    and businessdate='05/18/2022'
```

Will return rows. If I try the "broken" query with just the `storenum` and `businessdate` with just the `disastrouscount` calculation will it return rows.

Comment: I suspect these are not the _exact_ queries that you run, because I see no logical reason for them to behave the way you describe.

Comment: @mustaccio I know, those are the queries. Let me see if I can post some screenshots to show one vs the other. 
[![image.png](https://i.postimg.cc/cCBybnc8/image.png)](https://postimg.cc/4HySKnqJ)
[![image.png](https://i.postimg.cc/Zq1Kp6R8/image.png)](https://postimg.cc/mcysGz7k)

Comment: what version of Db2 for IBM i?  Are you current on PTFs?

Comment: I had to ask, 7.3 OS and yes on the PTF

Answer (score 1):

I'm with Mustaccio, there's no reason moving the calculated field should cause the rows to change.

I did notice that the statement being run in the working screenshot appears to be just the statement you're expecting...
[image]

whereas in the broken, you've picked up some commented out stuff first...
[image]

I also notice you've not terminated any statements, with a `;`.  I'd suggest you do so.  As the only explanation I can come up with is that you're picking up some code you don't intended to.  On the `Messages` tab of Run SQL Scripts, take a look at the statement actually being run.
[image]

In addition, you should always use ISO date/time format for literals.

It appears that `kitchensenttime` and `parkcartime` are timestamps, not dates.  Comparing them to a date forces the DB to implicitly convert either the column value or the literal.  It's better practice to explicitly do the conversions yourself.

Furthermore, '0001-01-01' is suspect, if the column is nullable, it's more likely that the columns are null and don't actually contain '0001-01-01-00:00:00.000000'.  If the columns are defined NOT NULL and the records are being written out using RPG op-codes, then RPG is defaulting in the '0001-01-01-00:00:00.000000'

```
--having this semicolon will ensure the parser doesn't see 
-- any prior statements as being a part of this one.
;
--try this
Select storenum,
       businessdate,
       kitchensenttime,
       parkcartime as delivertime,
       (parkcartime-kitchensenttime) as deliveryseconds,
       case
           when parkcartime-kitchensenttime>360 then 1
           else 0
       end as disastrouscount
from irislib.tblorder
where not(kitchensenttime = timestamp_iso(date('0001-01-01'))
          or parkcartime = timestamp_iso(date('0001-01-01'))
         )
    and parkcartime>kitchensenttime
    and businessdate= date('2022-05-18');
```

Comment: Good news bad news. Bad news, I had to reboot my computer. Since I was playing with different things I did not save the query so I can not recreate the issue. I think you and @mustaccio were right. I added the ';' and it threw an error. I pasted your query and it ran. If I put the case on it onto its own line my statement would run. 
The '0001-01-01' is what a different app uses for a null date. 
Good to know about the best practice about the timestamp_iso.
I guess we are going to have to close this one with an 'I bet you two were right' I can't tell you what exactly I did wrong.